# How to re-open code review?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer, source-control-explorer

I made a mistake while using Team Server Foundation. I had requested a code review and also added myself as a reviewer so I could add comments on each file. Once finished, I closed the review without realizing it would close it for everyone else.

How do I re-open a closed review? All it gives me is grayed out text or no available actions anywhere I try to open it (Source Control Explorer, Team Explorer, and Web).

Comment: A quick google search suggests that you need to create a new code review request: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4062e56-ff65-4e74-bf7a-a6ef4939e7b6/reopen-closed-code-review

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot re-open a code review, you will need to create a new one.

Answer (score 6):

You can't but you can still view the review.

1. In visual studio, in the **Team Explorer panel** click on **Pending Changes**.
   [image: Pending Changes]
2. Click on **Action** and select **Find Shelvesets**.
3. Enter your **username** in the **research box**.

   [image]
4. In  the list **click** on the code review you want to open.
5. The view as change for the **Shelvesets Details**.
6. In the **Related Work Items** section. **Open the work item** for the review.

   [image]
7. And there it is.

Comment: This only works for code reviews, that are based on a shelveset. It does not work for code reviews, that are based on a changeset.

Comment: A more generic solution to view closed code reviews is posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146666/how-do-i-view-comments-from-an-earlier-code-review-in-team-foundation-service